# what is the minimum size of a database table- Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am curious to ask is there any standard for minimum size for a table as I can an empty table holds 16 KB in MySQL. And what are the content of table if there are no records?

Comment: I think it is  created code  like "crate table ..."

Comment: depends on too many factors, starting with the type of storage engine....

Comment: @duke please help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413071/validate-paypal-transaction-id-passed-by-android-in-magento-site)